# Download DragDrop user extension from Sencha Market

Tags: javascript, extjs, permissions, download, sencha-architect

I've trying to download the DragDrop User Extension for Sencha Architect 3, but the site keeps showing a popup saying that I don't have access to that download.
I don't see any option where I could pay for it or have my access enabled.

Does anyone have this user extension available or know how to download it.

PS: This is the only extension that I am not able to download from the website, all the others download just fine.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the sencha marketplace and not a programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't just you- there currently seems to be a privileges issue with that particular extension, you may be best contacting Sencha directly.